# NEO4J using an array or collection as a parameter in cypher query

Tags: java, graph, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to do call a cypher query (in java) passing in parameters to do something like:

```
WHERE node.property IN [{param}]
```

Full example:

```
START person=node:persons('Name:*')
MATCH person->[:Girl]->friend
WHERE person.Name IN [{Names}] AND friend.Hair = 'Blond'
RETURN person.Name, friend.Name
```

For the parameter I have tried using the following:

1. Collection containing strings
2. Array containing strings
3. Delimited string like "'Joe Blow', 'Blow Joe'"

I really thought the last one would work but I think the parameter is being replaced as a single string i.e. ["'Joe Blow', 'Blow Joe'"] and not ['Joe Blow', 'Blow Joe']. I proved this by passing in one value, and that worked. 
I tried tracing through the code but got lost in scala.

Any other options, thoughts?

Cheers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should work better if you remove the square brackets after the IN keyword, and use a collection as the parameter.

```
START person=node:persons('Name:*')
MATCH person->[:Girl]->friend
WHERE person.Name IN {Names} AND friend.Hair = 'Blond'
RETURN person.Name, friend.Name
```